# How do I define the average skills of a group in 50 Fathoms?

Tags: savage-worlds, 50-fathoms

I'm trying to understand the rules of Savage Worlds. I plan on playing 50 fathoms. One thing I didn't get despite reading all the rules and googling my question concerns how I should define what level to assign to a group for group actions.

Let say there is a crew composed of 3 PC and 5 NPC. One PC has boating skill of 1D10, the 2 other PC don't have any boating skill, 4 of the 5 NPC have a boating skill of 1D6 and the last NPC has a boating skill of 1D8.

**What is the boating skill level of the crew for a group actions to help the captain?** (Let's assume that the captain is the PC with the highest boating skill.)

Comment: Oh how I wish the official forums were up. I know for certain that this exact question has been asked several times on there, but as I've not run 50 Fathoms, I didn't really pay much attention. Hopefully you'll get an answer specific to the setting, because the way it handles ships and its crew is somewhat different to the core Savage Worlds rules

Answer (score 2):

Per the listing for Crew for ships in 50 Fathoms, "Sailors must have a minimum Boating skill of d6 to count as crew."

So the two PCs with no Boating skill don't count as all (though they could be gunners). Then the other six have to be compared to the total number of crew needed for the specific ship.

One of those needs to be the captain, making the primary roll, presumably the Wild Card PC with the highest Boating at d10.

So really, the only dice to worry about then are the other five NPCs where 4 have a d6 and 1 has a d8. Even using the average (as opposed to the lowest in the group), that's still a d6 for a group cooperative roll in Boating to aid the captain.

Hope that helps out!